# unable to send state of one component to other component in nextjs,getting this error: ncaught TypeError: setSelectedTag is not a function at onClick

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, mdx, next.js13

i have created state using useState hook , and i am trying to send the setState function as a prop to child component , but when i am using that function in a button 'onclick' it is giving me an error:
setSelectedTag is not a function at onClick

page.tsx:

```
export default function Home(post: Post) {
   const [selectedTag, setSelectedTag] = useState('All');
   const arrString = [];
   return (
      <BlogFilter
         selectedTag={selectedTag}
         setSelectedTag={setSelectedTag}
         tags={arrString}
      />
   );
}
```

blogfilter.tsx:

```
export default function BlogFilter(
   tags: any,
   selectedTag: any,
   setSelectedTag: any
) {
   return tags?.map((tag: any) => (
      <button
         key={tag}
         onClick={() => {
            setSelectedTag(tag);
         }}
      >
         # {tag}
      </button>
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page.tsx file, when you're sending the props to the BlogFilter component:

```
<BlogFilter
   selectedTag={selectedTag}
   setSelectedTag={setSelectedTag}
   tags={arrString}
/>
```

Instead of:

```
export default function BlogFilter(tags, setSelectedTag, selectedTag) {
   // ...
}
```

You need to destruct the props, which will assign the matching property names/values to the passed in variables, like so:

```
export default function BlogFilter({ tags, setSelectedTag, selectedTag }) {
   // ...
}
```